# Extract data from Angular 7 service using RxJS to subscribe to DotNetCore WebAPI

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I'm new to RxJs.

We have a DotNetCore api, which returns a response model, with a Generic for the data:

```
public class SingleModelResponse<T> : ISingleModelResponse<T>
{
    public Boolean DidError { get; set; }
    public String ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

The controller returns it like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{organisationId}/stats")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStats(int organisationId)
    {
        var response = new SingleModelResponse<OrganisationStatsDTO>();
        try
        {
            var result =  await _service.GetStatsAsync(organisationId);
            response.Data = result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.DidError = true;
            response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return response.ToHttpResponse();
    }
```

My angular service is set up to receive the OrganistionStats  :

```
   loadStats(organisationId: number): Observable<OrganisationStats> {
     const url = '/api/Organisation/' + organisationId + '/stats';
     return this.http.get<OrganisationStats>(url).pipe(
       map(response => response),
       tap(data => console.log('Stats: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
       catchError(this.handleError)
     );
   }
```

The trouble is that it's not the OrganisationStats that is being returned but the SingleModelResponse. I'm having trouble working out how to change the service to extract the OrganisationStats from the data property.

```
  loadStats(organisationId: number): Observable<OrganisationStats> {
    const url = '/api/Organisation/' + organisationId + '/stats';

    return this.http.get<SingleModelResponse>(url).pipe(
      map(response => response),
      tap(data => console.log('Stats: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `map(response => response.Data)`?

Comment: Brandon, yes, this does work. However, I get a warning that the object OrganisationStats doesn't have a data property, which is annoying. I was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Comment: `this.http.get<SingleModelResponse>(url).pipe(map(response => response.data))` should work, as long as you have defined the type `SingleModelResponse` and declared it to have a `data: OrganizationStats` property.

Comment: This is where it might get tricky, as SingleModelResponse will be returning many different data types in data.

Comment: Declare it as a generic type `SingleModelResponse<T>` with a `data: T` property

Comment: I have in the C#, how do I do the same in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be quite simple really. In the service, I replaced the get(url) with http.get(url) and the warning went away.

```
loadStats(organisationId: number): Observable<OrganisationStats> {
   const url = environment.api_root + '/api/Organisation/' + organisationId + '/stats';

   return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
      map(response => response.data),
      tap(data => console.log('Stats: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
   );
```

}